# Visual Studio, Unable to save files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

All of a sudden I am not able to save any files that I used to be able to. Before I go the route of uninstalling VS2013, figured I would ask if anyone has ever seen this type of error before.

I am running VS Studio 2013 RC 2

What's odd is the at the end of the file it's always a random string, which is why I am posting this, I never seen this kind of issue before.

[image]

Comment: Not that likely to be caused by VS.  You obfuscated the path too much to make the call.  Reboot the machine, disable anti-malware, kill processes one by one with Task Manager.  RC2?  Really?

Answer (score 0):

Does your solution have .xaml files? If so look at this: [VS 2013: Output files are locked and prevents further compilation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793464/vs-2013-output-files-are-locked-and-prevents-further-compilation)